# Cannot get HTML form values, form tag closing prematurely

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, spring-mvc, jstl

I am trying to populate a table with each rows as individual forms with the help of JSTL. 
The view itself is returned as a ModelAndView object from controller to a AJAX success function and is appended to the page. 
The view is rendered and appended just the way I wanted. 
The newly appended view also contains the ajax call to pass the form values to the controller.

**Problem** I am not getting the values of the form in the jquery function.
I inspected the code in chrome and found that the form tag in each row is closing immediately. The input elements are placed outside the form tag.

jsp form with jstl :

```
 <tr>
    <form class="period${count}">   
            <td rowspan="3">Period ${dispcount}</td>
            <td>Subject</td>
            <c:forEach items="${period}" var="day">
                <td>
                    <div id="dat_${count}_${day.key}" class="period${count} day">${day.value.sub}</div>
                    <input style="border: none" type="text"
                    name="inp_${count}_${day.key}" id="inp_${count}_${day.key}"
                    value="${day.value.sub}" class="inperiod${count} hideit" />
                </td>
            </c:forEach>

            <td><input type="button"
                onclick="testFunction(${count},'${classname}',this)"
                class="hideit inperiod${count}" value="save" /> 
                <input
                type="button" class="hideit inperiod${count}" value="cancel"
                onclick="myFunction('period','inperiod',${count})" /> 
                <input
                type="button" class="period${count}" value="edit"
                onclick="myFunction('period','inperiod',${count})" />
                </td>
    </form>
</tr>
```

jquery within the newly rendered code:

```
function testFunction(count,cname)
{     
 var x=$(".period"+count).serializeArray();

  var jso=JSON.stringify(x);
  alert("form values"+jso);

 var url = "./myAjaxFunction";   //controller method

 $.get(url,{str : jso,classname :cname},function (data) {

$.each(data, function(key, value) {

      $("#dat_"+count+"_"+key).html(value.sub);

    });
   myFunction("period","inperiod",count);

 });

}
```

I need the data passed to the controller to be in this form because it used in other places. This logic works fine when all the code is in the same jsp (not appended using jquery).

Script with ajax call and appends the ModelAndView:

```
 $(function () {
            $("#Classes").change(function () {

                var x=$('#Classes option:selected').val();
                 alert(x);

                 var url="./classLoaderAJAX";

                $.post(url,{classname :x},function (data) {

                    //var html = $.parseHTML(data);
                    $("#icontainstuff").append(data);
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: I worked around the problem by assigning the form's id to the `<tr>` and retrieving all inputs within it using `$("#trid input").serializeArray();`